# How can I send some data with sleekXMPP that is NOT picked up by a chat client?

Tags: python, networking, xmpp

I want to use XMPP as a "dumb data transport" for my app as it has users, a contact list, and ways round NAT.

SleekXMPP seems great - it makes it really easy to connect, get contact and send a chat message.

But how should I send data that is not a chat message? even if I change the message "type" I still see the messages in my regular chat client.

I serialise all my own data, so I don't need multiple types, just an easy way to send data over XMPP without spamming someones chatlog!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/XMPP_IM_Client_Design_Guidelines#When_making_a_custom_extension.2C_add_new_elements_to_.3Cmessage.3E.2C_.3Ciq.3E_or_.3Cpresence.3E_stanzas) about how to make your own XMPP extension.

You have to choose between sending data using an `<iq>` or `<message>` stanza.

`<iq>`s go from exactly one client to exactly one other client. They can contain your own XML data, but the `<iq>` element MUST have only one child element. But you must have a presence subscription to be able to send these (you must be in their "contact list"), otherwise you can't know which clients are currently online.

`<message>`s can be delivered to multiple clients the recipient is currently using. They follow the delivery rules for the type of message you use, you should read [RFC 6121 § 5.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-5.2.2) for details.

Comment: Another important distinction between <iq> and <message>: <iq> is request and response (there must always be a response. For one-way data transmission, messages are better. If you don't include a <body> element, normal IM clients will not display it.